# Problem with sequencing 2 proximity sensors using Raspberry PI and Python

Tags: pi-2, sensor

I am trying my first (self-written) attempt at using a Raspberry pi for an electronics project and I thought it would be simple with all the great help that people generously put on-line.

I am attempting to prototype a scenario where, eventually, I will use 2 relays to trigger an 'a' or 'b' event.

So I thought, before I start with the relay I thought it would be simple to demonstrate the code by blinking an LED from a signal generated from a proximity sensor (HW-201 on Amazon and elsewhere).  Simple - of course.

However, where I have made it complicated is that the event is direction driven so I compare times from each sensor, that determines the direction and eventually (that's the plan) a relay will be energized depending on direction.

The code I have written does most of this (I haven't worked on the relay activation yet).
What I have found is that as long as the sensors are activated in the order D1,D2,D1,D2 then all works fine.  But if I try a sequence where the same detector is repeatedly activated - nothing happens i.e D1, D2,D2 D2 (only the first D2 signal is shown).
I must be doing something obviously wrong but i have tried and cannot find an explanation - can anyone help please.
Here is the code - remember it is my first attempt at writing something from scratch!

```
#Sensor prototype

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO # shortened to GPIO
import time

sensor1 = 16 #Change if different pin

Led1 = 11 #2 leds blinking

sensor2=18

Led2=13

t0=0#used for baselining time

t1=0#used for baselining time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) #Use the board pin numbering not broadcom
GPIO.setup(sensor1,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(sensor2,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(Led1,GPIO.OUT)#Red LED
GPIO.setup(Led2,GPIO.OUT)#Green lED
GPIO.output(Led1,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(Led2,GPIO.HIGH)

def sensor_state():#this function allows the state of the pins to be displayed
    if GPIO.input(sensor1)==GPIO.LOW:
        print("sensor1 is LOW")
    else:
        print("sensor1 is High")
    if GPIO.input(sensor2)==GPIO.LOW:
        print("sensor2 is LOW")
    else:
        print("sensor2 is High")
        
print("Detectors Ready")
print(" ")

try:

    while True:
        if GPIO.input(sensor1):
            GPIO.output(Led1,GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(Led2,GPIO.HIGH)
            t0=time.time()
            D1=t0#assigns a value for calculation
            D2=t1#assigns a value for calculation
            
            print(D1)#allows a check that the direction calculation is correct
            print("D1 Detected")#used to check the code works as expected
            print("D1:", D1)#used to check the code worksas expected
            print(D2-D1)#this determines direction either +ve or -ve
            t0=0#this sets the time back to zero
            
            sensor_state()#runs function
            
            while GPIO.input(sensor1):
                GPIO.output(Led1,GPIO.HIGH)
                time.sleep(0.1)#stops continual reporting of the state
   
        else:
            GPIO.output(Led1,GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(Led2,GPIO.LOW)
            time.sleep(0.1)
   
        if GPIO.input(sensor2):
            GPIO.output(Led1,GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(Led2,GPIO.LOW)
            t1=time.time()
            D2=t1
            
            print("D2 Detected")
            print("D2:", D2)
            print("Direction:", D2-D1)
            t1=(D2-D1)
            
            sensor_state()
            
            while GPIO.input(sensor2):
                time.sleep(0.1)
            
        else:
            GPIO.output(Led1,GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(Led2,GPIO.HIGH)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            
        
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Here is a snippet of the output - with explanation

This first block changes sensor 1 from High - Low

D2 Detected

D2: 1638616284.8731945

Direction: 9.227322101593018

sensor1 is LOW

sensor2 is High

1638616292.0946455

Then when D1 detects movement the Sensor states are reversed

D1 Detected

D1: 1638616292.0946455

-1638616282.8673234

sensor1 is High

sensor2 is LOW

Then the next time D2 is detected, sensor 1 is changed to High

D2 Detected

D2: 1638616527.3517601

Direction: 235.25711464881897

sensor1 is High

sensor2 is High

At this point any movement detected by D2 doesn't change the sensor state

Comment: should include the output of the code (we dont have the hardware setup to run it ourselfs) and then provide better details of what you were expecting to happen

Comment: "while GPIO.input(sensor2):"  this is going to remain in this tight loop as long as the input condition is true. Is this what you want?  Hard to know what you expect to happen, or what its actually outputting.

Comment: Thanks Chad G  - Here is the output - D1 Detected
D1: 1638616292.0946455
-1638616282.8673234
sensor1 is High
sensor2 is LOW
D2 Detected
D2: 1638616527.3517601
Direction: 235.25711464881897
sensor1 is High
sensor2 is High   - When I invoke sensor 2 again nothing happens.  I guess I don't want to be in a tight loop but haven't worked out how to get out of it